# How can we override default inline styling of material ui icons

Tags: material-ui

I have to use material ui 0.16.6 for one project. How do I size these icons? By default they are getting some inline styles. How to override them? Tried styling the following way but didn't work

```
import Remove from 'material-ui/svg-icons/content/remove-circle-outline';

<Remove size={15} />

<Remove width={15} />
```

Comment: Please share your code

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with className:

```
<Remove className="yourClassName" />
```

or with inline styles:

```
<Remove styles={{width: 15}}
```